# Visit visa for husband

Tags: visas, uk

I am going to travel on a Tier 2 visa to UK,can my husband travel along with me in a tourist visa and stay with me for 6 months as he can apply for his dependent visa only after 8 months as i am on a probation period for the first 8 months.Please help.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to expats.

Comment: It's about a T2 spouse getting a tourist visa.  Voting to reopen.